# Проблема GROUP BY в SQL Server HIBERNATE

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

Я не могу решить ошибку

```
Column 'cohort.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained 
in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Запрос вроде рабочий, поскольку на базу H2 все работает корректно, но на SQL Server нет. Вот сам запрос

```
@Query("select i.id, sum(r.dose) from Inspection i left join fetch i.cohort 
c left join fetch c.parent left join fetch i.user left join i.personal p 
left join i.result r where i.id in :inspection GROUP by i")
```

Буду благодарен Вашей помощи и подсказкам

Вот что прилетает в SQL Server Profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'select inspection0_.id as col_0_0_, sum(result5_.dose) 
as col_1_0_, cohort1_.id as id1_4_1_, cohort2_.id as id1_4_2_, personal3_.id 
as id1_36_3_, inspection0_.id as id1_28_0_, inspection0_.cohort_id as 
cohort_11_28_0_, inspection0_.date as date2_28_0_, 
inspection0_.exposure_time as exposure3_28_0_, inspection0_.height as 
height4_28_0_, inspection0_.intake as intake5_28_0_, 
inspection0_.next_measurement as next_mea6_28_0_, inspection0_.note as 
note7_28_0_, inspection0_.personal_id as persona12_28_0_, inspection0_.unit 
as unit8_28_0_, inspection0_.updated as updated9_28_0_, inspection0_.user_id 
as user_id13_28_0_, inspection0_.weight as weight10_28_0_, cohort1_.code as 
code2_4_1_, cohort1_.name as name3_4_1_, cohort1_.parent_id as 
parent_i6_4_1_, cohort1_.type as type4_4_1_, cohort1_.updated as 
updated5_4_1_, cohort1_.user_id as user_id7_4_1_, cohort2_.code as 
code2_4_2_, cohort2_.name as name3_4_2_, cohort2_.parent_id as 
parent_i6_4_2_, cohort2_.type as type4_4_2_, cohort2_.updated as 
updated5_4_2_, cohort2_.user_id as user_id7_4_2_, personal3_.birth_date as 
birth_da2_36_3_, personal3_.first_name as first_na3_36_3_, 
personal3_.last_name as last_nam4_36_3_, personal3_.middle_name as 
middle_n5_36_3_, personal3_.sex as sex6_36_3_, personal3_.tab_number as 
tab_numb7_36_3_, personal3_.transfer_id as transfer8_36_3_ 
from inspection 
inspection0_ left outer join cohort cohort1_ on 
inspection0_.cohort_id=cohort1_.id left outer join cohort cohort2_ on 
cohort1_.parent_id=cohort2_.id left outer join personal personal3_ on 
inspection0_.user_id=personal3_.id left outer join person person4_ on 
inspection0_.personal_id=person4_.id left outer join inspection_result 
result5_ on inspection0_.id=result5_.inspection_id where inspection0_.id in 
(@P0) 
group by inspection0_.id order by inspection0_.id asc ',N'@P0 int',1
```

Comment: GROUP by i это как? i это алиас таблицы, вероятно имелось ввиду GROUP by i.id

Comment: Даже при i.id ошибка не меняется, вы правы, групировка должна быть по id

Comment: Проблема не связана с SQL Server - синтаксис запроса специфичен для Hibernate, и до сервера он доберётся изрядно изменённым. Так что ищите ошибку именно на уровне Hibernate. Тег `[sql-server]` явно лишний...

Comment: Стоит взглянуть на реальный запрос, уходяший непосредственно в БД. Подозреваю, он выглядит примерно `select i.id, cohort.id, sum(r.rose), ... from ... group by i.id`. `cohort.id` упомянут в `select` выражении, но не указан в `group by`, отсюда и проблемы

Answer (score 1):

В SSMS есть Sql Server Profiler (Tolls).
Запустите для нужной БД и посмотрите, какой запрос приходит на выполнение.

Думаю как только Вы увидите текст запроса - сразу поймёте в чём ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про Sql Server Profile, запрос ужаснул, там реально в селекте есть sum(result5_.dose) as col_1_0_, cohort1_.id as id1_4_1_, cohort2_.id as id1_4_2_, personal3_.id as id1_36_3_, inspection0_.id as id1_28_0_ ..... и так далее, но как теперь это исправить пока не знаю

Comment: @АндрійШульгін, попробуйте прикрепить к вопросу итоговый sql-запрос. Как минимум это больше информации, а может специалисты hibernate увидят ошибку сразу.

Comment: Так и сделал, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

left join должен быть с связке с полями , по которым собственно и джоините (для SQL). Такой запрос не даст нужной структуры для (для SQL).

Comment: Не до конца вас понял